# Was Leia originally raised by her and Luke's mother?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, princess-leia

This is a question that's sort of looking for an out-of-universe answer.

In *Return of the Jedi,* Luke asks Leia if she remembers her mother.  Leia responds that she has faint memories of her being kind but sad.  Obviously, in the prequels, we learn that Padme died just after her children were born, making it strange that Leia has any memories of her.  But, at the time of RotJ, Bail and Breha Organa, Leia's adoptive parents, didn't exist yet, and we know Luke was raised by Owen and Beru.  So, originally, was Leia supposed to have been raised by her and Luke's mother?  If not, what was her initial origin?

Comment: Bail and Breha Organa died when the Death Star destroyed Alderaan